# Is there something with my code because it saves the same data in the database even different fingerprints are scanned?

Tags: c#, mysql, fingerprint

Good afternoon! I just want to ask if there's wrong with my code here? Especially in the streaming/database saving logic. This saves the same data into the database even if I use different fingerprints, which is **(42-4D-2E-06-07-00-00-00-00-00)**.  As I know, the data that is being saved should be different each finger. But even though I try all my fingers, the same data are being inputted into the db. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

*Also, sorry if my question would look confusing, I'm a newbie here and I'm still trying to learn the proper ways. :)*

```
        public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Sample Sample)
        {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap = ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample);
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bitmap, Picture.Size);
        this.Invoke(new Function(delegate ()
        {
            Picture.Image = img;   // fit the image into the picture box
                                   //string ping;
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    m.Position = 0;
                    DPFP.Template Template = new DPFP.Template(m);
                    MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
                    Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
                    fingerprintData.Position = 0;
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
                    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);
                    string ping = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);

                    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                    connBuilder.Add("Server", "localhost");
                    connBuilder.Add("Port", "3306");
                    connBuilder.Add("Database", "db_fingerprint");
                    connBuilder.Add("Username", "root");
                    connBuilder.Add("Password", "");

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);

                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_finger VALUES(@finger_id,  @finger_tag, @stud_id)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("finger_id", "");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("stud_id", txtstud_num.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("finger_tag", ping);

                    conn.Open();
                    int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (a > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint Registered.");
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_students SET is_registered = 1 WHERE stud_id = '" + txtstud_num.Text + "';";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Fingerprint Registered.");
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: `WHERE stud_id = '" + txtstud_num.Text + "';"` Please don't do that. Use parameters like your earlier code.

Comment: Is finger_id the column you are talking about? If yes I see you are passing empty to this. May be some default value being set at database side?

Comment: Maybe you read less than necessary. Try: ` Byte [] bytes = br.ReadAllBytes();`

Comment: When you run this, what is the length of `ping.Length` with the first fingerprint? With the second?

Comment: @G_S the finger_id is AI in the db.

Comment: @Nikolaus I'd try that. thanks :)

Comment: @mjwills they're all the same length. here is the actual length of the data
*42-4D-86-7C-06-00-00-00-00-00-36-00-00-00-28-00-00-00-4A-01-00-00-42-01-00-00-01-00-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-C4-0E-00-00-C4-0E-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF*

Comment: What is the sample and what is the capture parameter?

Comment: If you mean sample of data, it is that long binary lines above. the parameter of capture is bitmap, if I'm not mistaken that that is what you need..

Answer (score 0):

It’s these lines of code:

```
bitmap = ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample);
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(bitmap, Picture.Size);
```

You convert your sample to bitmap and add it to your db-Entity. Instead you should use the capture.
As Capture is of object-type I don’t know, if you have to convert it, but the desired line could look like this:

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap) Capture;
```

Edit: As I did further research, I realized, that my answer is wrong, but maybe you could use this [Tutorial](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/03/26/how-to-use-manualresetevent-in-c-to-block-one-thread-until-another-has-completed/) to find out, what your error could be.

Maybe you need to await your capture.

Comment: thank you for this, Sire! So far, this is the best solution I had, though it still not fixing the error for it creates another error which is _Unable to cast object of type 'DPFP.Capture.Capture' to type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap_ 
I will try to fix this myself first then will just go back here when I need help again. But thank you for all your efforts to help. I am new to C# and you all are very great helps :)

Comment: @GhoennWoods I‘ve updated my answer. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: Alright, I'll try this. Thank you very much for the helps, sire!